# Reporting JMeter Results in seconds, as oppose to milliseconds

Tags: jmeter

Is there anyway to make JMeter report results in seconds, as oppose to milliseconds?

Thank you,
Lena

Answer (score 1):

There is no property or setting in Jmeter that I know of to change the Response time results to *Seconds*

you will have to save the results & manually divide each response time value by 1000.

or you will have to write your own code to achieve this.

hope this will help.

Comment: I think you could have written it as comment as its not an answer.

Comment: @NachiketKate, This is in fact an answer to the concern or question raised by the user. Comments are used to clarify the doubts if you are unable to understand the question or if you feel the question is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure is this an answer to question? Its okay if you feel so and for your information, comments are not only for clarifying doubts. If you don't think so please have a look at million questions on SO.

Comment: @NachiketKate Please provide a better answer to the user if you have it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the time format(in seconds) in jmeter html report by modifying the javascript file. The steps are:

- Locate the file dashboard.js.fmkr in bin\report-template\content\js.
- Open the file and locate the line "//Create statistics table. In this
  method,you will see a switch case which corresponds to the columns in statistics table of html report.
- For example, case 3 is for "Error %" column, case 4 is for "Average"
  column and so on."

To change the "Average" column's time to seconds, modify the code as follows:

```
case 4:
item = (item/1000).toFixed(2);
break;
```

You can repeat this step for any other column.

Answer (score -1):

Modify `user.properties` in the `bin` folder to have the following line

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
```

Comment: change to ms to s